# Wait for variable change inside swift returning function

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE system where the peripheral sends parts of a whole message and I need to wait for the whole message before processing it. Within `peripheral(didUpdateValueFor characteristic:)` I process the messages and whenever I get a complete one, I set `flagDataAvailable = true`. And here's where I'm having problems:

```
// This function is called from another class
override func get(_ data: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {

    var payloadGet = [UInt8(bitPattern: Int8(-1))]

    payloadGet = getOrPut(data, false)

    return payloadGet
}

func getOrPut(_ data: [UInt8], _ isPut: Bool) -> [UInt8] {

    var command = [UInt8]()
    var payload = [UInt8]()

    if isPut {
        command = CommunicationDevice.buildPutDataApdu(data)
    } else {
        command = CommunicationDevice.buildGetDataApdu(data)
    }

    print("Sending command \(command)")

    bluetoothDevice.writeValue(Data(command), for: notifyCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)

    let resultLength = read()

    let statusWord: [UInt8] = [rxBuffer[resultLength - 2], rxBuffer[resultLength - 1]]

    if (CommunicationDevice.TRANSMISSION_OK == statusWord) {
        payload = Array(rxBuffer[0..<resultLength - 2])
    }

    return payload
}

func read() -> Int {

    // Here I need to wait until flagDataAvailable is true before continuing

    var nbBytes = 0

    flagDataAvailable = false
    nbBytes = rxBufferLength
    rxBufferLength = 0

    return nbBytes
}
```

I've tried using `uwait(delay)` but then I never receive the callbacks for the characteristic update.

Clarifying:

The change in flagDataAvailable is being made in the same class as the function that need to track it. My problem is in how to wait for that change without blocking the thread nor returning the function read() before there is data available

Comment: Post an NSNotification once you have received a complete message

Comment: @Paulw11 I must admit that I don't see how that would help me, since my issue is not that I don't have a way to track changes in flagDataAvailable (Since the variable is inside the same class as the functions) but that I need to wait inside read() (Or even before calling it) until it changes to true

Comment: You shouldn't wait. You should write non blocking code. I am assuming that the caller of `read` is outside of this class. Posting an NSNotification will allow you to execute the require code in response to the asynchronous completion of the read. If the caller of read is inside this class then just call the required code when the condition is met. You could also pass a completion handler block to `read` and invoke it once the read is complete.

Comment: @Paulw11 Right now a function outside this class calls get, which cals getOrPut, which sends a message to the peripheral and calls read to wait for the answer. If you see, I have a chain of returns to keep track of what's happening since the answer from the device doesn't contain any information regarding what I had asked for or if it was a get or a put. The way you're suggesting (Hope I'm not interpreting wrong or lacking in understanding) would make me separate read() from getOrPut(), breaking that chain of returns. And I honestly have no idea how to track the messages besides using this way

Comment: That is correct. You should handle events asynchronously.  The class that calls `getOrPut` should pass a completion handler. You save this completion handler in a property and once the read is complete you invoke the completion handler. You can use a structure such as an array to act as a simple queue if more requests may be received before the previous one has completed (or you can refactor `getOrPut` to return `false` if a request is already in progress - it is up to you)